# Auto re-sizing embedded videos

Tags: javascript, css, video, youtube

I've researched on this site and many others and tried solutions such as fivid.js and custom css and js but none have solved my issue. I want to find a simple solution for existing youtube videos on a website to resize according to screen size.

I think the issue might be that most of the existing youtube videos are embedded the following way:

```
<p align="center"> 
<object width="800" height="450"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ETLV4nz5xCI?list=UURoUPTn7sfJkIl6Md5XKkwg&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ETLV4nz5xCI?list=UURoUPTn7sfJkIl6Md5XKkwg&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800" height="450" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

How can I make it so that any video on a site coded this way re-size according to screen size?

Edit: The site has multiple pages (it's an eCommerce site) and each product has it's own video, which is about 20 thousand products. Most of the videos are coded like the code above, I wanted to know if there was a way they can re-size on its own similar to this [fitvid](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js) because I can't go through all 20 thousand products and redo the code myself. I'm also curious if this is possible with how the youtube videos are coded.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as we know that object and embed has been deprecated better to go with iframe.
Below snippet code allows to resize the video based on browser size.

**here is the working code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe frameborder="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;" height="100%" width="100%",
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ETLV4nz5xCI?list=UURoUPTn7sfJkIl6Md5XKkwg&amp">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: hi thanks, How would I do this so that it affects all existing youtube videos on the website, for example if there were a few hundred videos embedded in this similar fashion?

Comment: see we can plug multiple iframe in one webpage...
Now what you have to do create a responsive design webpage create your complete layout and wherever you want to show video just plug above code...
You will see above snippet code doesnt include any hardcode css so it will take height width from its parent...

Comment: I think I might be confusing you, allow me to clarify. I have a site with multiple pages (it's an eCommerce site) and each product has it's own video, which is about 20 thousand products. Most of the videos are coded like in the description, I wanted to know if there was a way they can re-size on its own similar to this [fitvid](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js) because I can't go through all 20 thousand products and redo the code myself. I'm also curious if its possible with how the youtube video are coded ?

Comment: I don't mind posting the site, but do you just want the source code of the youtube embed? In any case here is the source code of a particular page, most of the pages look similar to this view-source:http://www.shoppmlit.com/oracle-lights-60-61-dodge-pioneer-5-3-4-inch-led-inch-led-halo-2-sealed-beam-headlights-headlamp

Comment: nice website... will go through it and get back to u... :)